# Best way to store Multiple ConnectionStrings in ASP.NET Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web-config, connection-string

I have many databases (Over 50) that has same schema. Each one stores data of a different client. I am exposing CRUD operations through Webapi. Connection string is being changed at run time. Client passes database alias that correspond to a connection string in my web.config file

```
<add name="DatabaseNameAlias" connectionString="Data Source=hhhhhxxxu.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=abc;password=xyz;Trusted_Connection=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

that works well but the issue is we have to type in 50 connection strings in my web.Config file. It's not very manageable approach. Although connection strings are stored in one common database as well but if i try to fetch them from database for each web api call that looks bad as well. In that case i have to hit database for each web api request.

Can anyone help me with their experience. Any recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can load all your connections strings to an static dictionary object having key as dbname and value as connections string on application start and resume where ever necessary.

Comment: Will it be manageable e.g if we need to add or remove a connection string. In that case we need to compile and redeploy

Comment: May be its worth mentioning that api is hosted as azure app

Comment: As you said all connections strings are stored in a common database make a call to that database on application start and store all connection string into this dictionary object. so that logic of reading the connection string will never change. does that make sense.

Comment: If I add a new connection string in database do I need to restart the app

Comment: yes. how often will you change the connection strings ?

Comment: When a new client gets on board

Comment: one more thing you can do is cache the connection strings and refresh the cache every day once or twice or as often as you think is necessary.

Comment: > When a new client gets on board - how often that happens? Every hour? Every day?

Comment: That's not very often but I was just concerned even if once a year I still need to restart application

Comment: What's using the connection strings? Entity Framework?

Comment: Can you have one connection string and simply insert the required datasource into that string on demand?